# How to measure function performance ("now()" always gives me the same value)?

Tags: postgresql

Right now I am recording the start/stop times inside my functions using `NOW()` and storing them in a separate table as `TIMESTAMP`s. The whole process is messy, but the real problem is that the start and stop times are identical even though some of the queries are quite complex which leads me to believe that no matter how many times you call `NOW()` from inside a function, it will return the same value. I tried writing to a double Precision value but I am still getting a duration of 0.

How would I go about accurately getting the duration of a Postgres function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT) `now()`  (and it's standard SQL equivalent `current_timestamp`) return the time at the start of the transaction.

If you want to get the "real" current time, use `clock_timestamp()`.

Answer (score 3):

A @a_horse_with_no_name is absolutely correct - but for performance measuring you can use some tools:

1. build-in function execution statistics - see [`pg_stat_user_functions`](https://www.depesz.com/2008/05/15/waiting-for-84-function-stats/#more-1206)
2. an extension [plpgsql_check](https://github.com/okbob/plpgsql_check) has integrated profiler [enter link description here](https://github.com/okbob/plpgsql_check#profiler)